# Change MS Access 2010 subdatasheet name default to [NONE]

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to set the default value for tables "Subdatasheet Name" to [None] instead of [Auto]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*SubdatasheetName* is a user-created property, which means the property does not exist in the `TableDef.Properties` collection until you assign a value to it.  When that property has not been set, Access uses *"[Auto]"*, and there is no way to make it use something else as the default value for the property.

You could use VBA to `CreateProperty("SubdatasheetName", dbText, "[None]")` for each of the local tables in your database. However you would need to do that again for any new tables you create.

Allen Browne discussed this topic in greater detail at [Problem Properties](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-09.html).  That page includes code you can use to set *SubdatasheetName* to *"[None]"*.